# How to implement "model entity state changes". My solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I’d like your opinion about my solution.
I have Employees data imported from an external database.
For the purpose of my application I can only see Employee details, change the Employee’s state (possible values are Enable, Disabled, Deleted) and edit some Employee attributes.

The editing part is not implemented yet. Here is only my solution to change employees state.
When an employ is imported , its state is Enabled.
This is the representation of possible state transition :

[image: Employee state transition]

An enabled item can be disabled. A disable item can be enabled or deleted. Deletion (soft deletion) is permanent. To delete an item it must be disabled first.

This is the “foreach” part of my Index.
Action links are rendered based on employee State:

**Index view**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fullname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ml-1" title="Details">
                <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
            </a>


            @if (item.State == EnumState.Enabled)
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs ml-1" title="Edit">
                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("UpdateState", new { id = item.Id , action=EnumAction.Disable})" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs ml-1" title="Disable">
                    <i class="bi bi-toggle-on "></i>
                </a>
            }

           
            @if (item.State == EnumState.Disabled)
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("UpdateState", new { id = item.Id, action=EnumAction.Enable })" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-xs ml-1" title="Enable">
                    <i class="bi bi-toggle-off"></i>
                </a>
                
                <a href="@Url.Action("UpdateState", new { id = item.Id, action=EnumAction.Delete })" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs ml-1" title="Delete">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                </a>


            }
           
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The UpdateState method is called passing two parameter : the employee *id* and the *action* to perform. The action is used in the view to show/hide buttons.

Links are rendered as in the image below:

[image: action link based on employee state]

First row is for Deleted items, the second row is for a disabled item and the last one is for an enabled employee.

I have two views : Details and UpdateState.
Both uses a partial view _employeeDetails that shows employee data (serialnumner, fullname, …).

This is the **EmployeesController code**:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if(id==null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

    if(employee==null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(employee);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(Employee model)
{
    
    return PartialView("_employeeDetails", model);
}


public ActionResult UpdateState(int? id, EnumAction action)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

    if (employee == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    ViewBag.Action = action;

    return View(employee);
}



public ActionResult Enable(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

    if (employee == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if(employee.State != EnumState.Disabled)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    employee.State = EnumState.Enabled;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}



public ActionResult Disable(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

    if (employee == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (employee.State != EnumState.Enabled)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    employee.State = EnumStato.Disabled;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}



public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);

    if (employee == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (employee.State != EnumStato.Disabled)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    employee.State = EnumStato.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

**UpdateState view**:

```
@model GESTPref.Models.Employee
@using GESTPref.Models


@{
    var title = "";

    switch (ViewBag.Action)
    {
        case EnumAction.Enable:
            title = "Enable employee";
            break;
        case EnumAction.Disable:
            title = "Disable employee";
            break;
        case EnumAction.Delete:
            title = "Delete employee";
            break;

    }
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = title;
}

<h2>@title</h2>

@{
    Html.RenderAction("EmployeeDetails", "Employees", @Model);
}

<div class="form-actions no-color mt-4">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs ml-1 btn-custom-sm" title="Back">
        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i> Back
    </a>

    @{

        switch (ViewBag.Action)
        {
            case EnumAction.Enable:
                <a href="@Url.Action("Enable", new { id = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs ml-1 btn-custom-sm" title="Enable">
                    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Enable
                </a>
                break;
            case EnumAction.Disable:
                <a href="@Url.Action("Disable", new { id = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-xs ml-1 btn-custom-sm" title="Disable">
                    <i class="bi bi-slash-circle"></i> Disable
                </a>
                break;
            case EnumAction.Delete:
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs ml-1 btn-custom-sm" title="Delete">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete
                </a>
                break;

        }
    }


</div>
```

What do you think?
Probably I could use just one view for Details and UpdateState. In the Details view all buttons would be hidden.